Comedy series with a white bearded sensei and 4 or 5 guys
I used to watch a series as a kid, where there was a white bearded Sensei (very similar to the one in Kill Bill) and he had 5 guys who were learning from him. They had to do some nasty things like eating nasty food or sometimes balls or toy cars where thrown at their junk.
I watched it in the mid-2000s I think, but can't remember how it was called, and I can't find anything about it on the internet.
EDIT
I think it was orginally in Japanese but I could be wrong. It was live action with real people. Those 4/5 guys were made to do silly and embarrassing tasks, and at the end the loser had always something thrown at their junk. It was very Takeshi's castle inspired, just different.

Country/language? Live action or animation? Anything else form the story?

I think it was orginally in Japanese but I could be wrong. It was live action with real people. Those 4/5 guys were made to do silly and embarrassing tasks, and at the end the loser had always something thrown at their junk. It was very Takeshi's castle inspired, just different.

This is MTV's Fist of Zen.

The show consists of a team of 5 people (usually British males between 20 and 30 years old but sometimes females), under the supervision of a Japanese man, called the Zen master, played by actor Peter Law,and voiced by actor Silas Hawkins who assigns them rituals they must accomplish to allegedly reach Zen enlightenment.
The show consists of nine "Zen rituals", each of which presents the victim with some form of pain or discomfort, and must be completed in silence, and sometimes in a given period of time.

Here's the old Zen Master, and here's a (dubbed) clip:



